# MERN. Blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

I was trying to send req to server but got 'blocked by CORS policy' I got ngrok running on backgrond and I'm using it's link as baseUrl in axios,I've use app.use(cors()),"proxy":"link' on the front part and I also had tried http-proxy-middleware in which I was doing this,but I still get CORS troubles

```
http-proxy
----------
  app.use(
    proxy('/auth/google', {target: 'http://localhost:2000', changeOrigin: true})
  );
  app.use(
    proxy('/api/**', {target: 'http://localhost:2000', changeOrigin: true})
  );
```

```
Express
--------
require('dotenv').config();
require('./server/models/Query');
require('./server/models/User');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const keys = require('./server/config/keys');
const authRoutes = require('./server/routes/authRoutes');
const queryRoutes = require('./server/routes/queryRoutes');
const feedRoutes = require('./server/routes/feedRoutes');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(queryRoutes);
app.use(feedRoutes);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
});


app.use(cors());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 2000;

app.listen(PORT);
```

```
authRoute
---------
router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const {email, password, type, fName, lName, city} = req.body;
  console.log('body from signup', res.body);
  try {
    const user = new User({
      type,
      fName,
      lName,
      city,
      email,
    });
    await user.save();
    const token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id}, process.env.COOKIE_KEY);
    console.log(token);
    res.send({token});
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(422).send(err.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just should've moved cors() before any route

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to handle cors in express servers. Try out this one. I am using this code segment in my every node express servers to resolve the cors.

```
//Cross Origin Handle Middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 
  'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  if( req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
    req.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});
```

You have to use this middleware after the mongoose connect. No need to use cors library for that. If you are going with this middleware approach. I think this would help. :)

Comment: nah,I still got this:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://bfceac75.ngrok.io/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: You removed `app.use(cors());` this code segment when you are using the middleware. Right? Ah ha. You are using proxy too. Using proxy is also a method of avoiding cors. Just test the api removing those proxies and puttng the exact url for the http request.

Comment: and I'm still getting this error,anyway thanks for the help